# stop integer from expanding when using \seq_item

Tags: expl3, sequence

I have two sequences: `\l_words_seq` containing: { dans, [DP, la, maison, ]foc } and
`\l_glosses_seq` containing: { in, the, house }. I would like to create another sequence `\l_final_seq`  from `\l_glosses_seq` that inserts the items from `\l_words_seq` matching the regex `^(\[(DP|NP)|\]\w* )` at the corresponding positions. The result should be { in, [DP, the, house, ]foc }

```
\int_new:N \l_counter_glosses_int

\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \l_words_seq {dans, [DP, la, maison, ]foc}
\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \l_glosses_seq {in, the, house}

\seq_new:N \l_final_seq

\int_zero:N \l_counter_glosses_int

\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_words_seq  {
    \regex_match:nnTF {^(\[(DP|NP)|\]\w* )} { #1 } 
    { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_final_seq {#1} }             
    {
        \int_incr:N  \l_counter_glosses_int 
        \seq_put_right:No \l_final_seq { \seq_item:Nn  \l_glosses_seq  {\int_use:N \l_counter_glosses_int}} 
    }
}

\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_final_seq  {  #1~ }
```

But my result is

```
house [DP house house ]foc
```

How could I fix this? I tried `\seq_put_right:No` but it only works when I append the integer and not the item corresponding to that integer.

Comment: always show a small but complete example. That makes testing easier. And please stick to the naming scheme, there should always be a module prefix in the variable and command names, so e.g. `\l_words_seq` should be `\l_jupiterjones_words_seq`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :) Could you please elaborate on how my example isn't small enough or not complete so that I can make more efficient posts in the future? What should my example have looked like instead? And I'll definitely take your advice on the naming scheme since I haven't given naming variables much thought.

Comment: There should be a full document that I can copy & paste in my editor and compile directly.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `\seq_put_right:Ne` (or `Nx`) instead, to fully expand the inserted item before adding it to the sequence.

The `o` type performs a single expansion, which isn't enough where you are trying to get an item from a sequence by an index that is itself stored in a variable.

Using `e` type (or `x` type) will expand the item, including the integer value, which will give you the expected results.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_mymodule_glosses_int

\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \l_mymodule_words_seq {dans, [DP, la, maison, ]foc}
\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \l_mymodule_glosses_seq {in, the, house}

\seq_new:N \l_mymodule_final_seq

\int_zero:N \l_mymodule_glosses_int

\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_mymodule_words_seq  {
    \regex_match:nnTF {^(\[(DP|NP)|\]\w*)} { #1 } 
    { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_mymodule_final_seq {#1} }             
    {
        \int_incr:N  \l_mymodule_glosses_int 
        \seq_put_right:Ne \l_mymodule_final_seq { \seq_item:Nn  \l_mymodule_glosses_seq  {\l_mymodule_glosses_int}}
    }
}

\seq_use:Nn \l_mymodule_final_seq { ~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I have replaced the last part by `\seq_use:Nn` instead of using inline mapping.

---

Alternatively, you can use `\seq_pop:NN` to pop the value from the sequence to a token list. Then, `o` type expansion (or `V`, which is preferred over `o`) will work fine to expand the token list variable.

```
\seq_pop:NN \l_mymodule_glosses_seq \l_tmpa_tl
\seq_put_right:NV \l_mymodule_final_seq \l_tmpa_tl
```

Comment: is there a reason you are using `x` and not just `e`?

Comment: @daleif No. Using `e` expansion will work fine in this example.

Comment: I think the Expl3 team is suggesting using `e` and only use `x` then really needed.

Comment: I didn't know that. I actually preferred `x` over `e` for no reason. Thanks for pointing out anyway.

Comment: @JSLee Thank you for your answer and also thank you guys for the comments. I'll need to read up on this concept of expansion.

Comment: @JSLee I think they have been cleaning up their internals going from `x` to `e` most places, which is why I noticed it. It is also listed on page 10 in `expl3.,pdf`

Comment: I see. Thanks. :)

Comment: Your other answer was no mistake, by using a simple `\par` without the superfluous check  it would've been perfectly fine.